# How to pre-create ASP.NET temp files

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, virtual-directory

I have a web site that has thousands of virtual directories pointing to the same code. When ever we do a deployment, every time a session hits one of the virtuals the asp.net files recreate and if there are many sessions to the server this takes lots of CPU and slows down the server. I am looking for a way to create one ASP.NET temp folder and copy it for the rest of the virtuals during deployment. I simply want to do a copy not have IIS fire and recompute for each virtual. Has this been done before or does anyone have any ideas? It looks like IIS uses some type of hash per virtual.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible but if the application is the same, why don't you use a single virtual directory with url rewrite ?

Comment: Unfortunately the app relies heavily on the virtual setup. It is a pretty big application and changing that code would be a major undertaking.

Comment: I understand that IIS uses a shadow copy to avoid locks and such but if there was a setting that says all virtuals use the same code and it would just copy that would solve my problem.

Comment: You might try precompilation, but ASP.NET does have some limitation on that side unless one day ASP.NET Core 1.0 is out.

Comment: We already pre-compile but the ASP.net temp files still generate

Comment: Internally ASP.net relies on these Temporary ASP.net file (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs,69cdab2cfa57caf8) and I'm not aware of any mechanism that will allow to change this behavior. The only solution I can see to optimize performance would be to use URL rewriting. In addition to have only a single ASP.net Temporary file, you will also optimize memory consumption, share JIT build result, etc. Could you tell us more about the application ?

Comment: One possible really dirty hack after looking at the code would be to set the `Thread.GetDomain().SetData(".appVPath", "XXX");` with the same value. ASP.net may share *things* and it may work. You can look at the `HttpRuntime.Init` method : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs,4e4012af7843ff07 for more information